# shell scripting: write to file

Tags: c, shell, scripting

I have to take in the command: `echo 'slkdjf' > filename`
so the user types in "echo", the string they want to type, and the file name they want to type into. How would I write that in C to take in those commands.

This is what I have done so far.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int j = 0
    int i = 6
    char buff[100];
    FILE * fp;

    if(argv[0] == 'e' && argv[1] == 'c' && argv[2] == 'h' &&
       argv[3] == 'o' && argv[4] == ' ' && argv[5] == '''){
            while(argv[i] != '''){
                    buff[j] = argv[i];
                    i++;
                    j++;
            }
    }
    fp = fopen("\proc\hello\hello", "w");
    fwrite(buff, 1, sizeof(buff), fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Does it look right so far?

Comment: I don't know.  What does it do so far?  Does it compile?  Does it execute?  If it does execute, is it behaving in some unexpected way?

Comment: it's just a general understanding of it. i haven't compiled it yet or anything. just wanted to know if i'm on the right track

Comment: You seem to misunderstand how the `argv` array works. It is an array of strings, i.e null-terminated char arrays. Perhaps it is a good idea to look a bit more into C and get acquainted with how strings are treated before trying to write a shell.

Comment: ...and you should check (using `argc`) how many arguments your program received before trying to use them

Comment: ... And what do you think will happen  if the argument you want to copy into `buff` is longer than the 100 bytes you have allocated for `buff`? I don't want to be too rude but, as you asked.... your program here above doesn't look right.

Comment: Neither `\p` nor `\h` is a standard escape character sequence.  Your compiler should be shrieking at you to fix other problems too.

Answer (score 1):

`argv[0] == 'e'` isn't good first. `argv` is a `char**` so if you want to compare `argv[i]` with something, you should use `strcmp()`.
So, in order to test if the first word is `echo`, you have to do :

```
if(strcmp(argv[1], "echo") == 0) // argv[0] is your program name
{ //do something }
```

You should also notice that `argv[i]` is a `char*`, you can then use `strcpy` if you want to copy your string.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int j = 0;
    char buff[100];
    FILE * fp;

    if(argc < 2)
    {
        printf("There are not enough arguments\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if(strcmp(argv[1], "echo") == 0) // means you the user typed 'prog_name echo "something"'
    {
        if(argc > 4) // So you have 'prog_name echo "something" > filename'
                     // But you cannot do 'prog_name echo "something" >filename' this way
                     // Because '>filename' will be counted as 1 argument (1 word)
        {
            fp = fopen(argv[4], "w");
            fwrite(argv[2], sizeof(char), strlen(argv[2]), fp);
            fclose(fp);
        }
        else
            printf("Nothing to save\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```